# Polymorphic association for multi-type sign-up in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, polymorphic-associations

I am using devise for my application authentication. I am having a `User` model which is the sign-in/up model.

The functionality is in such a way that when the client i.e. the user signs up, he'll be taken to fill in the mandatory user-profile page. Everything worked fine using devise.

Now I have a new functionality, User can be of different types( lets say `A`, `B`,`C`)

If the user is of type `A`, then he has to follow the same sign up process and the same profile page.

If the user is of type `B`, then the sign up screen differs and awaits validation from administrator. Different changes for type `C` too.

All the different types have different profile pages and the fields differ.

So I decided to have a polymorphic association and this is how my models look

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  belongs_to :user_type, :polymorphic => true

end

class A
    has_one :user, :as => :user_type
end

class B
    has_one :user, :as => :user_type
end

class C
    has_one :user, :as => :user_type
end
```

I just wanna know is this the right way to go about the scenario or is there an better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want Rails' magic `type` column.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # create_table 'users' do |t|
  #   t.string :name
  #   t.string :type
  # end
end

# user_a.rb
class UserA < User
end

# user_b.rb
class UserB < User
end

# user_c.rb
class UserC < User
end
```

---

```
UserA.create(name: "bricker")
user_a      = User.where(type: "UserA").first
same_user_a = UserA.all.first

user_a == same_user_a #=> true
user_a.class          #=> UserA
user_a.is_a? User     #=> true
```

**Update**

```
class UserLogin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # create_table :user_logins do |t|
  #   t.integer :user_id
  #   t.string  :user_type
  #   t.string  :login
  #   t.string  :encrypted_password
  # end

  # devise ...
  belongs_to :user, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_one :user_login, as: :user
end

class Admin < User
  # create_table :admins do |t|
  #   t.integer :user_login_id
  #   t.string  :admin_name
  # end
end

class Moderator < User
  # create_table :moderators do |t|
  #   t.integer :user_login_id
  #   t.string  :moderator_name
  # end
end
```

Comment: But in this case would userA, userB, userC have their own tables? Because in my case, all those models have different columns. So I need to accommodate different tables for each one of them.

Comment: No. In that case you can use STI if you're into that sort of thing, and if there are only one or two special columns. Otherwise I would use a has_one association. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nevermind, I see that's what you already have. I'd say that's probably the best way to go - STI is usually a bad idea. You might be a little more specific with your User class, call it `UserProfile` or `UserLogin` or something, depending on what kind of information you're storing in that table. I'd also have one abstract `User` class that the other user types would inherit from.

Comment: @Rahul see my updates for how I would setup the associations - basically what you suggested, but utilizing ActiveRecord's `abstract_class` to allow the different user types to inherit from one base `User` class.

Comment: Thanx for the update. Let me make myself clear here. What you are trying to say is, UserLogin model/table would have devise specific details. Meanwhile 'User' table would have all the common columns and specific tables like 'Admin' and 'Moderator' would have their own specific columns.

Comment: is there any particular reason you have the polymorphic association in the updated code?

Comment: The `User` class won't have a table, as it's abstract. Think of it just as a way to group the user types. If you wanted to share more columns, you could make another class called `UserProfile` which would store stuff like `:name`, `:bio`, `:avatar_id`, etc. You could also place those columns into the `UserLogin` table (and probably rename it to something a little more generic).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17382/discussion-between-rahul-and-bricker)

Answer (score 1):

I've been into the same thing before

I would strongly advice to use non-polymorphic separate models and share the common functionality with mixins.

I had the same setup you've described and had to refactor it later since it became really bloated and complex as project was developed

Comment: Thanx for the reply. It would be great, if you could guide me to any resource that would help me do it...